# Angular login parse json

Tags: android, json, angularjs

I am making an android app in ionic. I am working on the login page. I want to check for the return json value and redirect user to other page or display error.

My code:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, MyServices, $location) {
        $scope.login = {};
        $scope.login.username = "";
        $scope.login.password = "";
        var loginsuccess = function (data, status) {
            if (data['valid'] != "false") {
              //   $state.go('app.playlists');
              alert('success');//Not working
            }
            else
            {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login failed!',
                    template: 'Please check your credentials!'
                });
            };
        };
        $scope.loginbutton = function () {
            MyServices.login($scope.login).success(loginsuccess);
        };
    })
```

json returned from server:

```
{"valid":"true"}
```

Comment: Sorry, Edited the question

Comment: Can you console.log the data variable or show the MyServices.login code? You might have to do 'data.data.valid' instead of only 'data.valid'.

Comment: try with `data.valid != false` or `data[0].valid`

Comment: That worked. data.valid thankyou but  i am unable to change page using $state.go('app.playlists');

Comment: you don't injected $state on the controller